# Add a column whose value depends on another row's value

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I'm trying to implement an "auto-fail" kind of column in a table that includes scores for evaluations like below:

| Employee | Category | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Foo | 5 |
| John | Bar | 4 |
| Randy | Foo | 3 |
| Randy | Bar | 0 |
| Daniel | Foo | 2 |
| Daniel | Bar | 1 |
| Joe | Foo | 1 |
| Joe | Bar | 0 |

I wanna create another column ('calculated score') such that, if their score in the Bar category is 0, they get a 0 on their overall score (basically, their score on Foo also becomes 0). Otherwise, it will just reflect their current score

So in the example above, the desired outcome will be:

| Employee | Category | Score | Calculated Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Foo | 5 | 5 |
| John | Bar | 4 | 4 |
| Randy | Foo | 3 | 0 |
| Randy | Bar | 0 | 0 |
| Daniel | Foo | 2 | 2 |
| Daniel | Bar | 1 | 1 |
| Joe | Foo | 1 | 0 |
| Joe | Bar | 0 | 0 |

Where Randy and Joe will now have 0 overall scores because they got 0 in Bar

I was able to achieve this in a spreadsheet app (though I'm not sure if my method is the most elegant way) by making a helper column that works as an "indicator" if an employee has an auto-fail score or not by concatenating their employee ID(for the sake of this sample table we'll use Employee field) to the category and score:

| Employee | Category | Score | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Foo | 5 | JohnFoo5 |
| John | Bar | 4 | JohnBar4 |
| Randy | Foo | 3 | RandyFoo3 |
| Randy | Bar | 0 | RandyBar0 |
| Daniel | Foo | 2 | DanielFoo2 |
| Daniel | Bar | 1 | DanielBar1 |
| Joe | Foo | 1 | JoeFoo1 |
| Joe | Bar | 0 | JoeBar0 |

And finally, in the calculated score column, I used COUNT to check if there is an instance of CONCATENATE(Employee, 'Bar0'), and if there is, then set it to 0, otherwise, set it to their score:

=IF(COUNTIF(D:D, CONCATENATE(A2, "Bar0") ) >  0, 0, C2)

| Employee | Category | Score | Indicator | Calculated Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Foo | 5 | JohnFoo5 | 5 |
| John | Bar | 4 | JohnBar4 | 4 |
| Randy | Foo | 3 | RandyFoo3 | 0 |
| Randy | Bar | 0 | RandyBar0 | 0 |
| Daniel | Foo | 2 | DanielFoo2 | 2 |
| Daniel | Bar | 1 | DanielBar1 | 1 |
| Joe | Foo | 1 | JoeFoo1 | 0 |
| Joe | Bar | 0 | JoeBar0 | 0 |

Is there any way to implement something like this in SQL?

Comment: You cannot add a calculated column, you would implement your query as a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function (to only look at the rows for the current employee) along with a filter (to restrict to the 'Bar' rows for this employee) and a `CASE WHEN` to match on this value. If it's 0, then return 0 (regardless of the category of the current row, but still only matching those of the current employee), otherwise return that row's score.

You'll need to create a view though, a generated column won't work here (can't refer to other rows, though there might be other problems too).

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  Employee VARCHAR(6),
  Category VARCHAR(3),
  Score INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO employees
  (Employee, Category, Score)
VALUES
  ('John', 'Foo', '5'),
  ('John', 'Bar', '4'),
  ('Randy', 'Foo', '3'),
  ('Randy', 'Bar', '0'),
  ('Daniel', 'Foo', '2'),
  ('Daniel', 'Bar', '1'),
  ('Joe', 'Foo', '1'),
  ('Joe', 'Bar', '0');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
     , CASE
         WHEN MIN(score) FILTER (WHERE category = 'Bar') OVER (PARTITION BY employee) = 0 THEN 0
         ELSE score
       END AS calculated_score
FROM employees
ORDER BY employee, category;
```

| employee | category | score | calculated_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Daniel | Bar | 1 | 1 |
| Daniel | Foo | 2 | 2 |
| Joe | Bar | 0 | 0 |
| Joe | Foo | 1 | 0 |
| John | Bar | 4 | 4 |
| John | Foo | 5 | 5 |
| Randy | Bar | 0 | 0 |
| Randy | Foo | 3 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tukapb9vqjjJuUuB2koUsb/0)

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly on PostgreSQL. Quick question, if I need use just standard SQL, will the modifications to this solution to achieve the same goal be too complex?

Comment: @whatdahil: technically FILTER is part of the sql standard, but it is fairly rare (postgresql & sqlite only I think). You can replace it with `WHEN MIN(CASE category WHEN 'Bar' THEN score END)` (you can also add a `ELSE 0` or `ELSE null` before the `END` if it looks clearer to you).

Answer (score 2):

You can just check if their `'Bar'` score of 0 [`exists`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS). Quick, conceptually and syntactically simple: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vtCWgXpi)

```sql
select *, score*(not exists(select from employees 
                            where employee=e.employee 
                            and score=0 and 'Bar'=category))::int
          as calculated_score
from employees e
order by 1,2;
```

If they do have a `0`, you end up multiplying their scores by `0`. If they don't, by `1`, so no change.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a subquery within the SELECT statement, which looks up the "Bar" category score for the same employee. It allows for a dynamic calculation of the "Calculated Score" based on the employee's performance in the 'Bar' category.

```
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT CASE WHEN score = 0 THEN 0 ELSE score END FROM employees WHERE employee = e.employee AND category = 'Bar') AS calculated_score
FROM employees e
ORDER BY employee, category;
```